# Foreach - Array inside another array - Returns only 1 index - I need to return all values ​of key_number:

Tags: php, laravel, foreach, controller

I want to get from my answer only the values ​​of the key_number; even though I return the foreach inside another foreach, it returns only one index and not the two values ​​of the request.

**Controller**

```
foreach (array($request['key_number']) as $notaFiscal) {
    foreach($notaFiscal as $notas) {
        dd($notas);
    }

    // $moviment->document()->create($notasFiscais);
}
```

**Request**

```
dd($request);
```

```
 +request: Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\InputBag {#1535
    #parameters: array:8 [
      "type" => null
      "people_id" => 5
      "company_id" => 1
      "vehicle_id" => 2
      "department_id" => "12179"
      "document_id" => null
      "document_type_id" => 1
      "key_number" => array:2 [
        0 => array:2 [
          "title" => "New Title"
          "key_number" => "444444"
        ]
        1 => array:2 [
          "title" => "New Title"
          "key_number" => "555555"
        ]
      ]
    ]
  }
```

**Request foreach index key_number**

```
array:2 [ // app\Http\Controllers\MovimentController.php:50
  0 => array:2 [
    "title" => "New Title"
    "key_number" => "444444"
  ]
  1 => array:2 [
    "title" => "New Title"
    "key_number" => "555555"
  ]
]
```

**foreach inside foreach return only one index**

```
array:2 [ // app\Http\Controllers\MovimentController.php:51
  "title" => "New Title"
  "key_number" => "444444"
]
```

Return all index key_number, not one index.

Comment: `return $key_number = collect($request->key_number)->pluck('key_number');`

Comment: Hi @didenetahi, That's so beautiful, thank you so much, you're awesome. I had heard of the pluck, but hadn't tried it yet.

Thank you very much, success.